# Getting Viewpager page number

Tags: android, imageview

I have a view pager with a fragment in it with a grid view with image views. I download images and put them on the grid view. Can I access the view pager position from my image adapter?

`ViewPager`:

```
pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_menu);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();   
Log.d(TAG, "ViewPager adapter created");
this.mPagerAdapter  = new MyPagerAdapter(fm);
mPagerAdapter.testText = "TITS";
pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

`ViewPager` adapter `getItem` method:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    fragmentPosition = position;
    Log.e("PageAdapter", "Creating fragment at: " + position);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("activity", DefinedValues.images);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("type", "info");
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("page", position+ 1 + "");

    String request = Json.stringToJson(DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.clear();

    StringAsyncRetriever net = new StringAsyncRetriever();
    net.setListener(MyPagerAdapter.this);
    net.execute(request, DefinedValues.GET_DATA);
    fragment1 myFragment = new fragment1();
    return myFragment;
}
```

Setting up adapter in `fragment1`:

```
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_fragment, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`StringAsyncRetriever` downloads information about six thumbnails once the fragment is created. When it is done it creates six images, adds them to global container and when setting adapter for `imageView`, downloads the images accordingly, sets them up. What I need is to access page number in `imageAdapter` to set up correct image.

Comment: i don't understand what doesn't work. can you describe what fails ?

Answer (score 0):

> vp is the viewPager ,
>
> static int currentPage;
>
> pageListener = new PageListener();
>
> vp.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);
>
> you have to put a page
> change listener for your viewPager. There is no method on viewPager to
> get the current page.
>
> private int currentPage;
>
> ```
> private static class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
>         public void onPageSelected(int position) {
>             Log.i(TAG, "page selected " + position);
>                currentPage = position;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> or in the latest packages you can also use
>
> vp.getCurrentItem()

you can declare currentPage as static, then you can it from adapter by using

**activityname.currentPage;**

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to just pass the position to adapter. Didn't think through, when asking question.